# How do I convert mongoose query results to plain javascript?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I need help

I have a lot of confusion about using mongooses to control query results.
Mongoose's query result is sometimes plane js object and sometimes mongoose object.

I want to show my confusion in code.

```
        (async function (){
        try{
            const user1 = await User.findOne() 
            console.log(user1.constructor) // => mongoose Object => read only

            const user2 = await User.findOne().lean()
            console.log(user2.constructor) // => javascript Object => readable and writable

            const users3 = await User.find()
            console.log(users3.constructor) // => javascript Object => readable and writable
            //Why javascript object ? Despite not using lean()func

            const user4 = await new User({
                memberType : 'local',
                id : 'myId',
                nick : 'myNick',
                isAdmin : false,
                joinDate : new Date().toISOString(),
                sex : 'm'
            })
            .save()

            console.log(user4.constructor) // => mongoose Object => read only

            const user5 = await new User({
                memberType : 'local',
                id : 'myId',
                nick : 'myNick',
                isAdmin : false,
                joinDate : new Date().toISOString(),
                sex : 'm'
            })
            .save()
            .lean()

            //TypeError: (intermediate value).save(...).lean is not a function

        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })()
```

so.. my questions are...

1) why users3.constructor is plane javascript object ? despite not using lean()

2) how to make mongoose object user4(save result) to plane javascript ?

(In case of user4, lean has an error.)

I would be very grateful if you could reply.

have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

> why users3.constructor is plane javascript object ? despite not using
>   lean()

`users3` is an `Array` here, an `Array` of mongoose object; because `find` return an `Array` of matching elements.

`findOne` in other hand would return you a mongoose object directly.

---

> how to make mongoose object user4(save result) to plane javascript ?

Using the `.toObject()` method, `lean` is an option only to queries like `find`; it do not apply to `save`, as explained in [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1723)

**Example** :

```
const user5 = (await new User({
  ...
}).save()).toObject();
```

---

[image]